# CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

In my plugin I sending request with curl, and it's works fine for a long time.
Sudden on my test server stop works, then I added this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

and now it works fine.

Can anyone explain to me way it's stop working and is safe to disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER?

Comment: http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert on that test server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably stopped because your client can no longer verify the remote certificate. You could figure out for sure by checking the return/error code curl returns for you.

Why can't it verify that? Probably because your CA cert bundle isn't featuring the correct (set of) certs.

Is it safe to disable remote cert verification? No. You then allow man-in-the-middle attacks as you can no longer be sure you're actually talking to the correct server and not an impostor.